# Select top 2 rows in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to retrieve top 2 tables from my employee list based on salary in hive (version 0.11). Since it doesn't support TOP function, is there any alternatives? Or do we have define a UDF?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Yes, here you can use `LIMIT`.

You can try it by the below query:

```
SELECT * FROM employee_list SORT BY salary DESC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: @Akshay it works, i guess u missed the semicolon at the end

Comment: Why sort by, why not order by?

Answer (score 4):

Here I think it's worth mentioning `SORT BY` and `ORDER BY` both clauses and why they different,

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> SORT BY <column_name> DESC LIMIT 2
```

If you are using `SORT BY` clause it sort data per reducer which means if you have more than one MapReduce task it will result partially ordered data. On the other hand, the `ORDER BY` clause will result in ordered data for the final Reduce task. To understand more please refer to [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SortBy#:%7E:text=Hive%20supports%20SORT%20BY%20which,give%20partially%20ordered%20final%20results.) link.

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> ORDER BY <column_name> DESC LIMIT 2
```

**Note:** Finally, Even though the accepted answer contains `SORT BY` clause, I mostly prefer to use `ORDER BY` clause for the general use case to avoid any data loss.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from employee_list order by salary desc limit 2;
```