# How to find longest duration in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have small issue in hive logic. I need to find longest customer in my data set.My dataset contains values as below

```
customer       time
 cust 1        8:01
 cust 1        8:02
 cust 2        8:02
 cust 2        8:03
 cust 2        8:04
 cust 2        8:05
 cust 3        8:02
 cust 3        8:03
```

Here in my example, cust 2 has the longest customer based on the total time he/she has engaged. cust 1 total count is 2, cust 2 count is 4 and cust 3 count is 2. My issue between 8:01 to 8:05,  the longest duration belongs to cust 2 . Hence cust 2 should come as result.  How can i implement this logic.

Please help

Note: need solution without limit operation

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select customer
from t
where time >= '8:01' and time <= '8:05'
group by customer
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: I dont have option to do limit operation

Comment: Can u help on this without applying limit

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give the desired

```
    Select distinct customer from table where 
     (distinct time) = (select max(distinct time) from table)
```

or if you want desired as per group reduction

```
         Select  customer from( 
           (Select customer,(max(time)-
         min(time)) as time_diff
          from table group by customer
         order by time_diff desc LIMIT 1)
          ;
```

Comment: Can u elaborate ?

Comment: the first solution will mean the customer who has the largest duration (max) of all in the list the next solution  be the longest not the largest

Comment: How come rownum logic came? Where is the field romnum?

Comment: then it must be limit 1 as you specified sql in the tag as well first it came from that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441744/select-top-2-rows-in-hive take a look at this refer this